# Retrieve Coordinates from Array

Tags: maps, coordinates

I would like to put all my coordinates into an array and have a loop display each one but with a Google function.

Here's the code, which draws the points on google map:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
var arrPos = new Array([37.772323, -122.214897], [21.291982, -157.821856], [-18.142599, 178.431], etc. );

var flightPlanCoordinates = [ + 
   for (i=0; i<arrPos.length; i++){
      new google.maps.LatLng(arrPos[0]) + ", "
   }
   + "];"
```

I know you can put a loop in an array but is there an alternate method to retrieving the points from the array??

tks

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
For(var i in arrPos){
  new google.maps.LatLng(arrPos[i][0],arrPos[i][1]);
}
```

Greets

Thomas van Latum